# Using Brew to Install rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to take a coursera class on Ruby from Johns Hopkins. The Mac OSX set up instructions require that I download homebrew and then install rbenv. I already have brew installed from stuff I had done a long time back, so perhaps this issue is because I screwed up installing ruby/brew a long time ago.

Here's the command that's giving me issues: `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
the response i get is this:

```
Warning: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed, it's just not linked
==> Installing dependencies for ruby-build: pkg-config, openssl
Error: Cannot link pkg-config
Another version is already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28
```

Update: Here's what appeared after running `brew doctor`:

```
Warning: /usr/local/bin isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local/bin
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin

Warning: /usr/local/share isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local/share
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `sudo chown -R $(whoami)` them:
    /usr/local/share/man
    /usr/local/share/man/man1
    /usr/local/share/man/man5
    /usr/local/share/man/mann

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
    /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.3
    /usr/local/bin/apm
    /usr/local/bin/atom
    /usr/local/bin/idle3.3
    /usr/local/bin/python3.3-32
    /usr/local/bin/pythonw3
    /usr/local/bin/pythonw3-32
    /usr/local/bin/pythonw3.3
    /usr/local/bin/pythonw3.3-32
    /usr/local/bin/pyvenv-3.3
    /usr/local/bin/subl

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFFileMonitor.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFsqlite3.7.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFSyncEngine.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
    /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
    /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
    /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
    /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/tcl.h
    /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
    /usr/local/include/tk.h
    /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    rbenv

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
    2to3
    2to3-2.7
    easy_install
    easy_install-2.7
    idle
    idle2.7
    info
    infokey
    install-info
    makeinfo
    pydoc
    pydoc2.7
    python
    python-config
    python2.7
    python2.7-config
    pythonw
    pythonw2.7
    smtpd.py
    smtpd2.7.py
    tclsh
    tclsh8.5
    texi2dvi
    texi2pdf
    texindex
    wish
    wish8.5

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
```

New Update:
I did `brew prune`, changed ownership of the files that it suggested (some of them could not be found). Finally, when i run `brew install rbenv ruby-build` i get the following errors:

```
Warning: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed, it's just not linked
Warning: ruby-build-20151028 already installed
```

The next step would be to do `rbenv install 2.2.3`, but rbenv command is not found. Seems that the installation failed somehow. `which rbenv` also produced no output.

Comment: Try running `brew doctor` and let us know the output. Should help determine your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to brew doctor, you can't edit the directories that it's trying to install files to. Try running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

etc, like brew doctor is telling you:

```
You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local/share
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share
```

EDIT:
You might want to take a look at this part of the output to list the things you need to run the command on.

```
You should probably `sudo chown -R $(whoami)` them:
    /usr/local/share/man
    /usr/local/share/man/man1
    /usr/local/share/man/man5
    /usr/local/share/man/mann
```

Comment: do I need to run `brew prune`?

Comment: Well, the links are said to be broken so I don't think it will hurt. But it's not necessary for the installation, they seem to be python-related links.